# Charts not using available space with Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, google-visualization

I have a problem with Flex for Google Charts. Div with charts is not using available height. Am I missing something? (colors and blue borders are for development purpose so I'm sorry for that...)

**CSS**

```
.pc-metrics-chart {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: var(--yellow);
}

.metric-ch{
  height: auto;
  flex : 1;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--success);
}

.ManagementCharts {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="pc-metrics-chart" id="pc-metrics-chart-proj">
      <div class="metric-ch">
        <div id="totalProjectChart1" class="ManagementCharts">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I was trying to play with the position, alignments, height of the chart as well, but I'm using it's auto height and I thought that Flex will fill available space under the chart:

[image]

Comment: We'll need some sort of [mre] to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `height` property and set it to `100%` to fill the remain space:

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}

.pc-metrics-chart {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: yellow;
 }

 .metric-ch{
   height: auto;
   flex : 1;
   justify-content: stretch;
   align-items: flex-end;
   position: relative;
   background-color: lightgreen;
 }

 .ManagementCharts {
   flex: 1;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: red;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="pc-metrics-chart" id="pc-metrics-chart-proj">
    <div class="metric-ch">
      <div id="totalProjectChart1" class="ManagementCharts">
        Here should be chart placed
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```